# How to completely replace Helvetica with San Francisco

Tags: iphone, safari, font

in iOS 9, the system font had changed from Helvetica to San Francisco. ***I love the change!*** However, it doesn't change it in pages in Safari. Is there a way to change it to San Francisco? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't change fonts without jailbreaking. If your device is jailbroken, you can copy your preferred SFUI font family from /System/Library/Fonts/CoreUI/ over the top of each Helvetica font in /System/Library/Fonts/Core/.

Comment: How do you jailbreak? Is it a hard thing to do? What risks does it take?

Comment: @awe I would not recommend it to everyone. It's not ‘hard’ but you do need some knowledge of the workings of iOS. Risks can be mitigated if you have a backup and are willing to update iOS. If you really want to try and you acknowledge the risks, you are welcome to ask a completely separate question regarding the specific version of iOS you are trying to jailbreak and the device model on which you are attempting it.